# Cannot insert duplicate value into datatable when updating record from textbox

Tags: c#

Trying to update records in my datatable using textboxes on a button click. The error message says is cannot insert a duplicate value, and shows the value that I have entered into txtID. This is the code for the update button:

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        String query = "UPDATE Bug SET Tester_ID=" + txtID.Text + "',Tester_Name= '" + txtName.Text + "',Application_Name= '" + txtApp.Text + "',Class_Name= '" + txtClass.Text + "',Line_No= '" + txtLineNo.Text + "',Error_Description= '" + txtDesc.Text + "',Source_Code= '" + txtSource.Text + "',Status= '" + txtStatus.Text + "')";
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection);
        adapter.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Data Updated Successfully");
    }
```

Comment: You probably want to include `Tester_ID` in a `where` clause, instead of updating all records in your table to have that ID (and all those other values).

Comment: If you write an UPDATE without a WHERE then you are updating every record of the database with the same values. Of course you are getting duplicate values. But this is trivial, More worrysome is your using of string concatenation to build an sql command. This is well known to be the source of Sql Injection attacks and parsing errors of various gravity. Lears ASAP how to write a parameterized query

Comment: So my query should be "UPDATE Bug WHERE Tester_ID...."?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 0):

You do not have `where` clause in that query, so it is updating all records in the table, which is making some records duplicate. Hence the error. 
The could be due to your defined table structure.

P.S. You should look for SQL injection attack and should parameterize your query to avoid it.

**Edit based on your comment**

```
String query = "UPDATE Bug Set Tester_Name= '" + txtName.Text + "',Application_Name= '" + txtApp.Text + "',Class_Name= '" + txtClass.Text + "',Line_No= '" + txtLineNo.Text + "',Error_Description= '" + txtDesc.Text + "',Source_Code= '" + txtSource.Text + "',Status= '" + txtStatus.Text + "' WHERE Tester_ID='" + txtID.Text + "'";
```

If Tester_Id is numeric, you don't need those quotes.

Where clause comes after Set.

Here is the **Parameterized** version:

```
String query = "UPDATE Bug Set Tester_Name=@Tester_Name,Application_Name= @AppName,Class_Name= @Class_Name,Line_No= @Line_No,Error_Description= @Error_Description,Source_Code= @Source_Code,Status= @Status WHERE Tester_ID=@Tester_ID";

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tester_Name", "XYZ");
// other params
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tester_ID", 10);
```

Comment: Yes, if Tester_ID is your primary identification of the record

Comment: I have changed the query to this and I have this message: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.'. My query currently looks like this: "UPDATE Bug WHERE Tester_ID='" + txtID.Text + "',Tester_Name= '" + txtName.Text + "',Application_Name= '" + txtApp.Text + "',Class_Name= '" + txtClass.Text + "',Line_No= '" + txtLineNo.Text + "',Error_Description= '" + txtDesc.Text + "',Source_Code= '" + txtSource.Text + "',Status= '" + txtStatus.Text + "'";

Comment: Updated my answer, Where clause should be the last.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Will be looking into what you have mentioned about SQL injection attacks now.

Comment: Thanks. Glad it helped, [mark it as answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) then